# Idiom for saying that someone is very dear to me?

Tags: idioms, idiom-request

I'm looking for an idiom which means someone is very dear to me. It could be used instead of the following expression in bold, for example.

> I can't let my daughter marry a stranger! **I didn't find her on the street!** She's my own flesh and blood.

By the expression in bold, I mean my daughter is not like a neglected child. She is too dear to be married off to a stranger.

Comment: I didn't find her on the street.

Answer (score 2):

She's **the apple of my eye**.
She's **my pride and joy**.
Or even simply She's **my daughter** (emphasis on "daughter" rather than "my") could imply all the rest.